# DatePicker getContextMenu() is null

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `DatePicker` and want to add a new `MenuItem` to `ContextMenu` of it.

```
DatePicker inputDate = new DatePicker();

try{

    MenuItem clearInput = new MenuItem("Clear");
    clearInput.setOnAction(e -> {
        inputDate.getEditor().clear();
        inputDate.setValue(null);
    });

    inputDate.getContextMenu() //returns null
            .getItems()
            .add(0, clearInput);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At this code I get `NullPointerException` at `.getItems()`, which means `inputDate.getContextMenu()` is null.

Why `getContextMenu()` returns null?

And how to fix it?

Or how to add a new `MenuItem` to `ContextMenu` of `DatePicker`?

Comment: wondering why you expect the picker to have a contextMenu (if you haven't set any)? If you mean the editor's default, ask the editor :)

Comment: @kleopatra, It has `ContextMenu`, because when I right click on input, the menu shows up (Undo, Redo, Copy, ...). Even `inputDate.getEditor().getContextMenu()` returns null.

Comment: yeah, you are right: the default contextMenu (that what you are seeing on right click) is managed by the behaviour which is not related to the contextMenuProperty of the control. Probably hard to change (maybe going dirty somehow to get hold of it), you might replace it completely, though.

Comment: @kleopatra , I replaced the default `ContextMenu` with a new one and with my `MenuItem`. It works perfectly. Fortunately that I don't need default `MenuItem`s. Thank you for your time @kleopatra .

Comment: glad you found a solution :) Closing this as duplicate (because the complete replace meets your requirement)